# Are Digital signatures used enough these days?

Tags: public-key, signature

So I'm currently working on a past exam paper related to cryptography, this question essentially asks the reader why digital signature schemes are not used today.

Yet, when I did my research on this topic online, I found out that most technologies do in fact use digital signature schemes. In fact I'm even confused by what this question means now and would appreciate if anyone has any input to what the lack of use related to digital signatures could mean. If there are any sources related to this, I would be grateful to read them.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously that question was asked before the age of Internet became secure (think HTTPS, SSL/TLS, IPSec, etc.)

In the age of secure Internet, almost all communication protocols employ digital signature as a form of authentication.

However, (and this still applies in some industrial sectors), physical paper signatures are still required legally (US, and other countries), as people unfamiliar with computers or smart phones may be tricked by scammers into authenticating unwillingly through digital signature.

Trivia: NIST required paper-signed IP statement from submitters for their Post-Quantum Cryptography standardization project, before their lawyers changed their mind recently.